# Create heatmaps in R from local coordinates

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a player movement dataset which has 2D player location coordinates every second. I'm looking to create a heatmap of where the player stay longer. I've seen a few answers on creating geographical heatmaps, but they're on maps, whereas in my example, it's in a confined indoor space. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you have something that looks like xy coordinates per second.  You can essentially count up how many times an xy pair appears in your data and then map a color intensity to a count value.